# How can I do this reverse number pyramid in C

Tags: c, numbers

the question is to make this number pyramid :

```
123454321
 1234321
  12321
   121
    1
```

I'm new to coding so can you tell me how to approach and how to think logically in this type of question.

this is my code:

```
    main (){
    int input;
    printf("Enter number of row: ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    while (input <= 0) {
        printf("Not valid.enter number of row: ");
        scanf("%d", &input);
    }
    int i,j,k, space;
    int temp, temp1;
    for(i=1; i<=input; i++){
        for(space=0; space<=input-i; space++){
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        for(k=j; k>=1; --k) {
            printf("%d", k);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this is my result of the code above:

```
    121
   12321
  1234321
 123454321
```

Comment: You are very close. Try reversing the order of the outer `for` loop. (You don't *have* to start at `1`, and you can decrement with `i--` instead of incrementing.)

Comment: BTW: it's `int main(void)`

Comment: The shown code demonstrates looping, looping "up", looping "down", looping to a counter from an outer loop, printing numbers. With all that already in place, what is your specific problem? Looks like you'd need very few tinkering attempts to get closer and closer to the desired output. That is assuming that you did write the shown code yourself. Or is this the "search for ready solutions" approach?

Answer (score 1):

you can try printing your first pattern using different logic, you might be able to reverse it easily.

if you want to use the same logic then,
try reversing your loops by doing something like

```
Original loop;
for(i=1; i<=input; i++)

After reversing loop:- 
for(i=input; i>=1; i--)
```

Comment: Nice. You are offering to help according to the compromise descibed here, aren't you? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Which means you expect OP to use this, update the shown code and then hope for more help by you. I am so with you. Very kind of you.